# MySQL wrong character encoding after updating from 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, character-encoding

I exported MySql database using PHP myAdmin to the `database.sql` file. Then I imported it to my local database using **MySQL WorkBench**.

When I have had **5.1 MySql server** on my Notebook it worked fine but after changing device and updating environment to **5.6.17** all non-latin characters where transformed to bushes.

It has to be an error with differrent verisions of database but I have no idea how to solve it.

At the server, `character_set` is `utf8_general_ci`

This is a specification of one of my local columns where error is visible:

```
Table: customers
Collation: utf8_unicode_ci

Column: name
Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
Definition: name varchar(255)
```

I tried to change character set on columns, tables and whole database without success.

How should I change encoding in my local database to import correct data from *.sql file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change encoding of the script file to UTF-8 too.

For example use this(check the encoding and swap it with the 'latin1' below):

```
iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 database.sql database-utf8.sql
```